# To label the graph by y axis on the line chart in plotly in R

Tags: r, data-science

[image]

To label the line by the value of y axis. I have plotted two graph in one ,in the first i am getting my result as of my need but in second it is showing values at lower axis

### how to display all value of x axis on the x plane .In my case i want to display all values from 1:18 in the x plane

```
ay <- list(
 tickfont = list(color = "red"),
 overlaying = "y",
 side = "right",
 title = "Modal price"
 )
 p <- plot_ly(M, x = ~Week, y = ~`Arrival(Tonnes)`,   
  type= "bar",mode= 'marker',
    marker = list(size = 10),name ="Weekly Arrival") %>%
  add_annotations(x = seq(1:18),
              y = M$`Arrival(Tonnes)`,
              text = M$`Arrival(Tonnes)`,
              xref = "x",
              yref = "y",
              showarrow = TRUE,
          
              arrowsize = .01,
              ax = 0,
              ay = -20) %>% 


     #2nd graph addition
   add_lines(x = ~Week, y = ~`Modal price`, name = "Weekly Modal  prices",   

  marker = list(size = 10), yaxis = "y2",mode="marker") %>%
           layout(
          title = "Model price vs Arrivals in Weeks", yaxis2 = ay,
          xaxis = list(title="Weeks") ) %>% 
 ##Problem here the values are not attaching with the graph continuity 
  
 add_annotations(x=M$Week,y=M$`Modal price`,text=M$`Modal    
   price`,xref="x",yref="y",
                showarrow=TRUE,arrowsize=0.1,ax=20,ay=-20)
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik basically i want to add the values in the graph according to its y-axis . In the first graph i.e, bar chart i am able to place value corresponding to it on its top ,but in the second graph i.e, line graph i not able to place the values on the line graph (they are being placed on the y-axis).

Comment: @RomanLuštrik can you help now

Comment: Without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), I'm not that compelled to dig into this, sorry.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik sir i just need values on the orange line of the charts